# Adding a Table Of Content to a Jasper Report?

Tags: jasper-reports, report, tableofcontents

How do I go about adding a Table Of Contents to a Jasper Report?

Comment: There is a way with the *Wave Book* from version 6 on, [see more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37862912/data-redundant-after-adding-report-to-report-books). So this would depend on the version you are using.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your are using iReport,

for example,

1. add a text field;
2. right click, choose `hyperlink`,
3. set `Hyperlink target` to `self`
4. and set `Hyperlink type` to `LocalAnchor`,
5. set the anchor value in the `Hyperlink Anchor Expression`.

after a pdf has been generated, you can click that `text field` which goes the anchor(bookmark if more precisely)

sadly, I don't think iReport can automatically deduce the TOC in a simple manner. So, you have to add these entries manually.

[image]